# confused about git push to a remote repo

Tags: git

I know maybe this question was asked alot but I am a bit confused about the path : 
I have a git username user_x and git server : git.my_server.com, I did the clone as following :

```
git clone ssh://user_x@git.my_server.com/path_to_work
```

I added a read me file, I ADDED , commited then I want now to make a push.

```
git remote add origin user_x@git.my_server.com
```

or

```
git remote add origin user_x@git.my_server.com/path_to_work
```

When I `git push origin HEAD`
I get : fatal: 'user_x@git.my_server.com/path_to_workt' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

or what exactly ??
Thank you

Comment: Git automatically adds the remote when you do `git clone`. You shouldn't need to do that. You could just push right away. Try running `git remote -v` to list configured remote URLs.

Comment: You need a protocol - in this case ssh://

Comment: show us your `.git/config` file. All your configs go there. Will have more information about your current state.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote add` is to add a remote GIT-Repo to your local copy. This has nothing to do with a push. When you clone a repo then the remote is already set.

You have to do something like:

```
git push origin HEAD
```

Comment: I get : fatal: 'user_x@git.my_server.com/path_to_workt' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: So if you really want to add this try `git remote add origin git.my_server.com`